# qt resize image in Qtextedit with the mouse

Tags: image, resize, qt5, qtextedit

My project is to implement a text editor like Word.
Every thing works fine except resizing an image with the mouse (like Word 2016)
How can i detect the image in a QTextEdit, how to select it and then resize it with the mouse.
I checked the example posted in stackoverflow which use a qdialog to resize images but i need to do it with mouse.
Any idea please?

Comment: I have written an answer once,but I have deleted it because I accepted no your response.I think that you think my answer was not good and not understandable.But I had solved this question by myself because I  also have searched this kind of question as you are doing,in my experience,at the present, there probably was no answer for it on the web.if you want to know answer,please give me some response or write the detail of question clearer.

Comment: Hello sir.. i was offline for a period of time and i did not check your answer..can you post it again,please

Comment: QImageFormat → QTextImageFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four ways for rendering in `QTextEdit`.

1.`QImageFormat`
  This is the most standard way in `QTextEdit`. The important thing is `QTextCursor` handling. 
2.`QTextObjectInterface`
  This is the second way but very useful.
3.`QGraphicsPixmapItem`
  you have to Import `QGraphicsView` & `QGraphicsScene` in advance but it is not constrained by `QTextBlock`.It is very liverty and freedom.

4.`QPainter drawImage`
  It is originally for the non-interactive way.I don't use it in this answer.

I recommend (1 or 2) & 3 combination.

**When mouse click**

1.You render image on the `QTextEdit`.

2.You click the image.

3.The cursor must move the before or after the image.

4.That is to say,the cursor position must be before or after the image.

5-a.I think you can catch the image-format by QTextCursor handling.

5-b.If you use `QTextObjectInterface`,you can catch "\ufffc" character.

6 `Imageformat` belongs to one character ,so you can select and catch the image by `movePosition` method with `KeepAnchor` flag in `QTextCursor`.

7. In advance, you prepare the QGraphics Engine.

7-1 You can catch the `cursorRect` and get the position on the `QTextEdit`.
   you may use the position of the cursorRect, and width and height of the image.
   you can specify the image by using them.

and then, you call QGraphicsItems. you call `QGraphicsScene.addItem()`

8. you prepare eight QGraphicsRectItem for mouse handling [image]and one QGraphicsRectItem for the Image.
9. This is the most important thing to exactly calculate the rect positions.
   You decide the standard position and make the hub of the eight rectitem position.

10.You define the control calculation in `QGraphicsRectItem` Subclass.
   You probably want to know the way of calculation...

This may be global object,because they are temporally used.

**When mouse move**

11.Approximately, I explain it.

If you mouse click on the rectitem of the left, [image]

I think you move mouse cursor to left, the image is expanding to right.

It seems to be the same control in MicroSoft Word.In a word, you may not think about the change of height.Needless to say, you must not change the eight rect item size.

It may be a trick , `QGraphicsRectItem.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor)` is helpful.

And I think the ratio of change is +1 or -1 is the best.
It is not complicated and very understandable,at least, at first.
I recommend that you don't match the moving of mouse cursor.
Eventually,it will be difficult for coordinating the size of Images by users.

13. you update width & height of `QGraphicsRectItem`.
    and you `setWidth` & `setHeight` simultaneously.
14. **This is very important**. you delete and reinsert Image over again and again at the same position.
    It seems to be automatically bigger or smaller by users .But the image is instantly deleted and added.
    Sure,you must reinsert the bigger or smaller image.
    You must reinsert at the same position. So you install `setKeepPositionOnInsert(True)`
    and after inserting, `setKeepPositionOnInsert(False)' may be important.Because after inserting, the position will be at the back of the inserted text.

**After**

15.If you end manipulating the image, you remove the rects from the Scene.

16.I forgot to say, it is probably needed `installEventFilter` for moving mouse and connecting the effects to rectItem.But if the rectItems are global, you can call them in the `QTextEdit`,mouseEvent Handling.

p.s. If you couldn't understand what I said, please don't hesitate to ask me by comment.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try to implement it